# Uniquely count value of multiple textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, this, string-length

I have 3 textareas, I want to uniquely count the value of each textarea and display it back

```js
$(".textarea").keyup(function(){
  $(".display").text($(this).val().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<div class="display"></div>

<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<div class="display"></div>

<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<div class="display"></div>
```

I want to only get the `length` of the particular textarea that is being typed into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method to get the immediate next `div.display`. This
method allows us to search through the immediately following sibling in the DOM

```js
$(".textarea").keyup(function() {
  $(this).next(".display").text($(this).val().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<div class="display"></div>

<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<div class="display"></div>

<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<div class="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".textarea").keyup(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".display").text($(this).val().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
  <div class="display"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
  <div class="display"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
  <div class="display"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".textarea").keyup(function(){
  $(this).next(".display").text($(this).val().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<div class="display"></div>

<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<div class="display"></div>

<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<div class="display"></div>
```